# Outlook in MacOS search issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, office365, spotlight, macos-ventura

**Problem**

trying to search mail in Outlook in a Mac computer. It can't find mails, even though the mails are in the inbox

1. Outlook Version: Office 365
2. Mac Version: MacBookPro (MacOS Ventrua
   13.1)

**Troubleshoot Steps**

1. Check if the search feature is enabled: Open Outlook, go to the
   "Preferences" menu, select "Search" and ensure that the "Include
   messages in Spotlight" and "Include messages from the Deleted items
   folder in each data file when searching in All Items" options are
   checked.
2. Rebuild the Outlook search index: Go to the "Preferences" menu in
   Outlook, select "Search," and click on "Indexing." Then click on the
   "Rebuild" button to rebuild the search index.
3. Check for updates: Ensure that Outlook is up to date by going to the
   "Help" menu and selecting "Check for Updates." If there is an update
   available, install it and restart Outlook.
4. Reset Spotlight: Go to the "Apple" menu, select "System
   Preferences," click on "Spotlight," and select the "Privacy" tab.
   Drag your hard drive from the Finder window to the list of locations
   excluded from Spotlight search, then remove it by clicking the "-"
   button. This will reset Spotlight and should allow Outlook search to
   work.
5. Reinstall Outlook

However, issue remains

Comment: It's suggested that you could try the troubleshooting steps mentioned in this article: [Troubleshooting Outlook search issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066#ID0EBBF=Outlook_for_Mac)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Hi Christy, sorry for the delay, I was waiting to access the client Mac when she is free. will let you know shortly

Comment: Looking forward to your reply! By the way, if my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: thanks Christy, I tried the solutions, issue fixed temporarily, but problem came back after 2-3 hours. Hopefully, there is a permanent solution or workaround

Comment: Considering that the problem disappeared briefly, it is recommended that you could try to uninstall and reinstall Office to check if anything is different.

Comment: I have reinstalled the Outlook365. the issue remained (see point 5 of my original post)

Comment: Same here as ppau2004, solved for me only for few minutes and the problem comes back.